# Is there any way to have curl connect and let me type and send pieces of the body as I type?

Tags: curl, http2, http-1.1

I would like to test the streaming part of our website with some command line tool.  Is there a way to send an http1.1 request using curl AND then have it go into a mode where as I type, it sends the data to the server keeping the connection open.  Also, will it be reading the response as the server sends it back?  (I kinda need that as well as the controller should be responding in real time).

thanks,
Dean

Comment: From the [curl man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl): "The command is designed to work without user interaction."

Comment: shucks!  want to post the answer and I can mark correct? @root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [curl man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl): "The command is designed to work without user interaction."